# Objective C Resize image as 2x image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image-resizing

I am resizing image but after resizing image is not returning in good quality here is my code

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
          scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

here is my code how it is call

```
UIImage *image = [self imageWithImage:self.selectedImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake((self.imageView.image.size.width*self.slider.value), (self.imageView.image.size.height*self.slider.value))];
```

result of image
[image: sma]

Here is the small image that i am scaling.

Comment: Define "not coming in good quality".

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.

For example,

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(signView.bounds.size, signView.opaque, 0.0);

    [signView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    // UIImage *imgMySignature = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    signView.img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I am rendering image from `UIView` i.e `signView`. You can use something like this.